# How to collapse the sidebar by default in ag grid

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid

I try to collapse the sidebar by default in ag grid. i don't want extend it until i click on the columns tap on the right side.

I tryed to do `[showToolPanel]="false"` but it will hide all the sidebar.

is there easy way to do that ?

https://next.plnkr.co/edit/UJRD2lrOQe6C7Lfs

[image]

Comment: by default it should be closed?

Comment: @ng-suhas yes it should be closed by default. is it possible to do that ?

Answer (score 13):

To do that you have to use the [`SideBarDef`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-side-bar/#sidebardef-configuration) configuration:

```
<ag-grid-angular 
  [sideBar]="{ toolPanels: ['columns', 'filters'] }">
</ag-grid-angular>
```

In that configuration you can set the `defaultToolPanel`, but if you do not specify this, it will be closed by default:

> The panel (identified by id) to open by default. If none specified, the side bar is initially displayed closed.

[plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/OZKS1q9JZyvfB1VxUxlW)